# Regex select second and third word in a string

Tags: regex

I've got a string where I need to aleays select just the second and third wodr in a string. Currently I can only select the first three words but I need to skip the first word.
I currently have:

```
^(?:[^ ]*\ ){2}([^ ]*)
```

Any help wouild be aprreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: But you captured the third word alright. Grab the Group 1 value.

Comment: `^\S+\s+\K(\S+)\s+(\S+)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the second and the third "word" as in 1 or more non whitespace characters:

```
^\S+ (\S+ \S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7QyVU3/1)

Or if supported with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=^\S+ )\S+ \S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/slAtPW/1)

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much! The lookbehind version worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regex you're looking for:

```
(?<=\s)([^ ]*)
```

Link to example: https://regex101.com/r/wSdzLe/1